# Match First Regex Character

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

Is there any regular expression to match first character of string to be either Underscore(`_`) or alphabets[a-zA-Z] the second character onward string can contain  [0-9a-zA-Z] or  only 2 special characters that are  '_' and '-'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[_a-zA-Z][\w-]+$
```

This is a character class with `_`, and the alphabet characters.  `\w` is alphanumeric plus `_`, so the cash is included in the character class.  `+` means "one or more."

Comment: The string should parse {_abc,abc_12-, ab12_bc_pqr-,a_12_12D etc} But should not parse {12ac,1_abc} i.e., start chacter should be always alphabet or underscore and rest string can contain alphanumeric values with only two special character that are { - and _}

Comment: Updated answer.  I forgot the very important start/end string anchors

Answer (score 2):

```
^[_a-zA-Z][\w-]*$
```

This should check for the first character for _, a-z & A-Z and from then onwards, alphanumeric, _ and '-'.

Edit: Replaced alphabetic with alphanumeric

Edit2: Removed unnecessary escape characters

Comment: ^[_a-zA-Z][\w-]*$ there was change that i did..else it would so build error.

Comment: I guess _ and - do not require escape characters. Thanks for pointing that out. :)